why does rows and colm become random numbers when i change the input to them
hello ive been making this simulation of a fire spreading through a forest and im basically done, the only issue is when i switch the numbers of rows and columns they become ginormous numbers out of nowhere, im sure im missing something simple but i just cant figure it out
#include <stdio.h>

void InfoInput(int *rows, int *colm, int *seed, int *fireProb){
    FILE *file;
    char line[256];
    file = fopen("Test.txt", "r");
    if (file ==NULL){
        printf("fatal error\n");
    }
    
    fscanf(file, "%d",rows);
    fscanf(file, "%d",colm);
    fscanf(file, "%d",seed);
    fscanf(file, "%d",fireProb);
}

void treeInput(char forest[][102], int rows, int colm, int *totTrees){
    FILE *file;
    char line[256];
    file = fopen("Test.txt", "r");
    if (file ==NULL){
        printf("fatal error\n");
    }
    
    char temp;
    int x=0, tempRow, tempColm;
    while(x<100){
        fscanf(file, " %c", &temp);
        if(temp == 'Q'){
            x=1;
            break;
        } else if(temp == 'A'){
            for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j<colm; j++){
                    forest[i][j] = 'T';
                }
            }
        } else if (temp == 'T'||temp == 'E'||temp == 'F'){
            fscanf(file, "%d", &tempRow);
            fscanf(file, "%d", &tempColm);
            if(temp == 'T'){
                forest[tempRow-1][tempColm-1] = 'T';
            } if(temp == 'F'){
                forest[tempRow-1][tempColm-1] = 'F';
            }
            else {
                forest[tempRow-1][tempColm-1] = '.';
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<colm; j++){
            if (forest[i][j] == 'T'){
                *totTrees += 1;
            }
        }
    }
   
}

void printInfo(char forest[][102], int rows, int colm, int seed, int fireProb, int totTrees){
    printf("S. Madden 9/20\n\n");
    printf("rows: %d\n", rows);
    printf("cols: %d\n", colm);
    printf("trees: %d\n",totTrees);
    printf("seed: %d\n", seed);
    printf("probability: %d%%\n\n",fireProb);
   
}


int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    char line[256];
    file = fopen("Test.txt", "r");
    if (file ==NULL){
        printf("fatal error\n");
    }
    
    int rows, colm, seed, fireProb, Time=0;
    int totTrees = 0;
    
    InfoInput(&rows, &colm, &seed, &fireProb);
    //manualInput(&rows, &colm, &seed, &fireProb);
    
    char forest[rows][colm];
    
    treeInput(forest, rows, colm, &totTrees);
    
    printInfo(forest, rows, colm, seed, fireProb, totTrees);

    return 0;
}

this is the file im calling
8
20
28
75
A
F 3 4
E 1 12
E 2 12
E 3 12
E 4 12
E 4 13
E 4 14
E 5 12
E 5 15
E 6 12
E 1 16
E 2 16
E 3 16
E 4 16
E 7 1
E 7 2
E 7 3
E 7 4
E 8 3
Q

the output is
S. Madden 9/20

rows: 777278548
cols: 1414812756
trees: 141
seed: 28
probability: 75%

this program works perfectly when there are 9 rows and 20 column(what i was testing it with) but when i switch it to 8 it goes willd
(btw this is a snippet of code where i found the issue was, theres more but it doesnt matter for this issue)
i honestly have no clue what the issue could be so any help is appreciated

Why do you have char line[256]; in all the functions, but you never use it?

char forest[][102] doesn't match the declaration of the array in main(), which has a dynamic width.

@Sarah Madden, void treeInput(char forest[][102], int rows, int colm, int *totTrees){ --> void treeInput(int rows, int colm, char forest[rows][colm], int *totTrees){ and re-order calling arguments.  Same  for printInfo().  Please report your results.

Because you declare forest in main with a dynamic number of rows and columns...
char forest[rows][colm];

Then you use it in your function signatures with a fixed number of columns.
char forest[][102]

This causes C to read and write beyond the boundaries allocated to forest overwriting data stored in other variables.

For example, lets say...
int rows = 3;
int colm = 4;
char forest[rows][colm];

forest is allocated a hunk of data 3 x 4 = 12 bytes wide. Some other variable might be allocated memory right after that.
___forest___
            __other__
123456789012345678901
^   ^   ^
^   ^   forest[2][0]
^   ^ 
^   forest[1][0]
^
forest[0][0]

For the purposes of brevity, I'll use forest[][10]. If you try to access this as forest[][10] that says each row is 10 bytes wide. forest[0][0] is the same, but forest[1][0] now points 11 bytes in and forest[2][0] is 21 bytes in.
___forest___
            __other__
123456789012345678901
^         ^         ^
^         ^         forest[2][0]
^         ^ 
^         forest[1][0]
^
forest[0][0]

As you can see accessing the data allocated to forest as char forest[][10] bleeds into other's data. In your case it's messing with row and colm.

thank you, i switched the array to just be a full 120 by 120 which i know probably isnt the best solution but its working now
